# Magento 2: Hide Admin Attributes Based on other Attribute's Value

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, customer-attribute

I've created some custom `yes/no` Customer Attributes in the admin area. Now I'm looking to hide some attribute fields if these are set to `no`

For example, I have a yes/no attribute called `branding_enable`, if set to no I want to hide the multi select field `branding_type` right below it:

[image]